# How do I counter inadequacies in answers to my question if more than a comment is needed?

Tags: discussion, answers

This concerns answers to my question
[Biden 'fake' interview: video of Biden's hands appearing the wrong side of microphones](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/50511/biden-fake-interview-video-of-bidens-hands-appearing-the-wrong-side-of-micro)

The most up-voted answer gives as evidence a Snopes article [Was Biden Filmed Talking to Press in Front of a Green Screen?](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/biden-green-screen/)

The problem for me is that a photograph at the start of that article clearly shows the fuzz of the grey microphone *in front* of Biden's right arm, whereas the purpose of said article is to demonstrate the mic should be *behind* his sleeve.

I have similar arguments concerning the other evidence provided in the answer.

**My quandary**

A recent comment hints that the most up-voted answer gives a convincing argument and should be accepted. I'm unwilling to do this without voicing my doubts.

To properly set out my counter-arguments to the claimed evidence would require visuals (it is after all a question about visual appearances). I don't think I can satisfactorily do this in comments. In any case, comments aren't the place for discussion.

**Question**

I'd like to accept an answer but don't feel able to without voicing and clearing up my doubts. How should I proceed?

(a) Go into great detail in comments

(b) Make my own answer that refutes the evidence given in other answers (I would prefer this)

(c) Something else that I haven't thought of

Comment: Nowhere in the comments on my answer do you mention the photograph at the start of the Snopes article. If you had done I would have made a simple addition to my answer - that the Snopes photo is from an entirely different angle from the 'fake' video, one in which the mike would be expected to be in front of Biden.

Comment: *mic is short for microphone. Sorry, that's my day job. (No, nothing with audio visual, just being a pedantic twerp).

Comment: @DJClayworth - It was only on reviewing your answer today (as a result of the prompt to accept it) that I checked everything more thoroughly to see if I should now accept. Maybe as  suggested by fredsbend, I should have merely listed my concerns very simply, rather than expecting to need pictures and argument. I'll look at it again.

Answer (score 4):

First, the green checkmark is yours to give, based on any criteria you want. You are under no obligation to give it at all, especially just because someone has suggested that you do. But if you do give it, you can take it back and give it to another! Not many other platforms do this.

I only see three options.

**Make an answer**: Another answer should only be an option if it's to be a competing answer. Do not use the answer space as an extended reply to another answer. If you answer, it must be able to stand alone, and it must answer the question. Some "response" to another answer is tolerable, but it shouldn't be the central point of the answer.

**Make comments**: You get 500 characters per comment. It's more than you think. I personally will do up to 3 comments if I need to express lengthy or complex criticism. More than that *is* chatty, and mods are inclined to delete comments that look like a wall of text.

**Make a chatroom**: If you have enough rep, you can create a chatroom and fill it up all you want. If you have lengthy feedback, create the room, then link to it in a comment. This seems the best option, especially if you expect replies equally lengthy. If you haven't the rep to create a room, just ask a mod in the main chat to set it up for you.